# Sending a Java program to a user whose PC has no Java installed

Tags: java, jar, exe

It might be a stupid question but I have a ready-to-be-sent Java Application compiled/built (I don't know what is the proper term is) in a `.jar` file. I believe you need Java in your computer to open such file. My program has GUI/JavaFX on it, I would like to send it to my friends for them to run it in their PCs that's why I placed it all into a `jar` file.

There's no issue in making the file work, I have sent the file to my friends who have Java installed and it worked fine, I was just curious if it is possible to send such file to a PC that has no java installed (maybe turn it into a legit application of some sort idk)

I've heard that you can change a `.jar` file into a `.exe` file but I'm not sure how does that work.

so the question is, how can I send my Java Program in a PC that has no Java installed and make it run it?

Comment: Executable JAR files require Java to be on the computer, as far as I know. Well, technically any Java application requires Java to be on the computer. But you can embed the Java Runtime with your application using `jlink` (Java 9+) or create a native executable/installer (with embedded Java Runtime) using `jpackage` (Java 14+). There are also third-party tools such as Launch4J.

Comment: Note that bundling a JRE with your application may affect which license you need and may have some legal implications. Make sure you understand them before you distribute your application.

Comment: @Hulk Just don't use the Oracle JDK and you don't have any license issues. There are a lot of alternatives out there nowadays, like, e.g., https://adoptopenjdk.net/